# Async data loading with ReactiveUI and GUI.cs

Tags: c#, reactiveui

I'm new to the reactive world so i'm struggling a little bit here x)
Here is my question:
How can i fetch async data, then bind them to a label ?

In my `MainView.cs`, i have a label:

```cs
Label usernameLabel = new()
{
    Text = "Loading",

    X = 0,
    Y = 1
};
```

And in my `MainViewModel.cs`:

```cs
public ReactiveCommand<Unit, UserProfile> LoadUsers { get; }

public MainViewModel(AppClient client)
{
    LoadUsers = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask(async _ => await client.GetUserProfile());
    LoadUsers.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(x => UserProfile = x);

    LoadUsers.Execute().Subscribe();
}
```

And `UserProfile.cs` contains basic things

```cs
internal sealed class UserProfile
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

First, i found this on internet, with a tutorial (i don't remember where tho), so i don't know if it was the right thing to do. I understand how to user commands associated with UI events etc, but not in this case.
So yeah, basically: How can i bind the result of this command to my label ?

Refs:

- gui.cs: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs

Answer (score 0):

Given, that `UserProfile` and `MainViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

You can do:

```cs
ViewModel
    .WhenAnyValue (x => x.UserProfile.DisplayName)
    .BindTo (usernameLabel, x => x.Text);
```

An easy way to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` is to let your viewmodel classes inherit `ReactiveObject` and use `ReactiveUI.Fody`

```cs
internal sealed class UserProfile 
{
    [Reactive]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

[Gui.cs reactive example](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/gui.cs/tree/main/ReactiveExample)

[ReactiveUI page about ReactiveUI.Fody](https://www.reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-models/boilerplate-code)